# c# webbrowser cannot read cyrillic

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding

When I write

```
richTextBox1.Text = wb.DocumentText;
```

Its showing the russian letters like that ������

What I can do?

Comment: What content type is being used?

Comment: Oded what you mean with "What type"?

Comment: Not type - `content type`. What encoding?

Comment: Oh the site is charset=windows-1251

Comment: Why are you not using UTF-8 then? Are you transferring all data with `windows-1251`?

Comment: How I can do that? I just writing the code above, I don't know how to choose encoding... Please modify your answer and show me

Comment: That's not all the code. How are you instantiating and using the `WebBrowser` contorl? Why not use `WebClient` instead?

Comment: I have a webbrowser control, I wrote wb.Navigate("Here is the site") and then wrote richTextBox1.Text = wb.DocumentText; I haven't try WebClient.

Comment: With `WebClient`, you can set the `Encoding` before you get the data, so that should work better for you.

Comment: Can you show me one example? I will give best answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx), you can set the encoding in order to retrieve the HTML and get it encoded correctly.

Untested example:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");

richTextBox1.Text = wc.DownloadString(myURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must install the cyrilic fonts to your browser in order to see charachters other then the standard types.

If its a desktop app you must look for if the required fonts exist in your font folder.

Or be sure that all your encoding meets the UTF-8 standard.

Comment: One assumes that if the OP was able to enter Cyrillic characters, they have the font installed.

Comment: thats not a valid assumption for all applications, some apps use fonts even if they are not installed on a system in wich case you see gibrish instead of the actual charachters.

Comment: The encoding is charset=windows-1251 so the fonts are installed

Comment: @Alkis, encoding and fonts are two completely different notions.