# How to transliterate Latin to Cyrillic text aspx.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to transliterate label text from latin to Cyrillic before print. I don't have idea how to do that. I've tried like this but didn't work.

```
    public void Komponenta()
    {
        words.Add("A", "A");
        words.Add("Б", "B");
        words.Add("В", "C");
        words.Add("Г", "D");
        words.Add("Д", "E");
        words.Add("Ѓ", "F");
        words.Add("Е", "G");
        words.Add("Ж", "H");
                ..and so on

}


  if (Label53.Text == "4")
                {
                    string source = Label47.Text;
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in words)
                    {

                        source.Replace(pair.Value, pair.Key);
                    }

                    Label47.Text = source;
```

Comment: In C#.NET you need to assign the replaced value back to the variable as @Wai-Ha-Lee has done in his answer

Comment: @Hais Baid worked, but with wrong letters, expected value is СУПА, but it output Ð¦Ð£ÐŸA, what is the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use

```
source = source.Replace(pair.Value, pair.Key);
```

As calling `Replace` ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1)) returns the modified string, as opposed to modifying the instance.

Comment: I assume you don't have any exceptions thrown as you don't mention it in your question.

Comment: I expect this label to be converted in cyrilic in my text file

Comment: You did say that in your question and I didn't notice. Your dictionary needs to have the keys and values switched, e.g. `words.Add("H", "Ж");`

Comment: But this don't work, it doesn't give error, but label is not converted in my text file

Comment: Ok,sorry it worked but this give me letters on another language, why is so that??? Expected IS СУПА but it output: Ð¦Ð£ÐŸA ???????

Comment: Have you tried `Label47.Text = {some Cyrillic text};` to see if that displays it correctly? Also, try looking at `source` after you iterate over each `KeyValuePair` in the quick-watch window ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2.aspx)) (if you can with ASP.NET, that is - I'm not sure) and see if it shows up as Cyrillic there.

Comment: you're right, i've tried with cyrilic text and it give the same wrong characters,what can i do now?

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll work for you, but have a look at [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12350264/1364007). For you, the code would be: `var wc = new WebClient(); wc.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"); Label47.Text = wc.DownloadString(source);`

Comment: how to achive this without webClient, my page is web deployed and with web client it give me error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error   wc.DownloadString("http://localhost:3125/Bar.aspx");???

Comment: I think you need to change the encoding for your string. I'm not sure what encoding you want to change from/to, but [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1922253/1364007) says *how* to change encoding.

Comment: It might also be useful for you to read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).